# RxJS How toggle and pause between observables?

Tags: javascript, rxjs, observable

Hi I'm starting with RxJS and I have a solution for the next problem but I don't like it, hope you can provide a better solution:

Imagine we have 2 streams we want to toggle:

- a request
- a timeout

Then, we want to switch between them, but one is resumed when other has an event and this is paused. E.g. we do a request when success, we do a timeout, when finish we do a request , when finish we do timeout, and so on.

In my solution I simulated the request with an interval, and I used "pausable()" , but I don't like the scalability of this solution:

```
import Rx from 'rx';

const requestPauser = new Rx.Subject();
const requestStream = Rx.Observable.interval(500).pausable(requestPauser);
const intervalPauser = new Rx.Subject();
const intervalStream = Rx.Observable.interval(500).pausable(intervalPauser);


requestStream.subscribe(function(){
  requestStream.pause();
  intervalStream.resume();
  console.log("request");
});
intervalStream.subscribe(function(){
  requestStream.resume();
  intervalStream.pause();
  console.log("interval");
});

requestStream.resume();
```

How RxJS experts would solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

You have the answer in the question.
I suggest switchMap
http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-switchMap

```
requestStream.switchMap(()=>Rx.Observable.interval(500));
```

I dont think a pausable is really required.

**UPDATE**

Since OP requires second observable to start after the first,
ConcatMap should be used.

Comment: thanks Suraj, with this I have a delay, but how I can then create a loop that both are repeated? 

    const responseStream = Rx.Observable.fromPromise($.getJSON('https://api.github.com/users'));
    responseStream.subscribe(()=>{console.log(1);});

    responseStream.switchMap(()=>Rx.Observable.just(2).delay(500)).subscribe(()=>{
      console.log(2);
    });

Comment: sorry this was wrong, because second subscribe is executed from start and it must be executed once the first one finish.

Comment: not you, my previous code, my explanation was not perfect anyway. I found a way to do what I want with concat, repeat and defer. I will post the solution